# Performance issues with jQuery mobile app

Tags: performance, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have a quite large app build using phonegap and jQuery mobile. I have about 5 pages withing the one HTML page (as per jQuery mobiles navigation system) all sharing one main JS file, which has 3400 lines of JS code.

The app has ran slower over the development period, and I Was wondering if it would make a difference splitting the app up into seperate HTML files and having them load into the DOM?

And secondly, would it also be worth splitting the javascript up so only javascript needed on the page is currently loaded with the page?

Like shall I have the whole 3400 lines of code loaded on device ready? or inject needed JS along with the page?

Comment: pretty sure you can answer this one on your own using common sense...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep as Nathan said I think you already know the answer.

I'd definitely recommend splitting your application into separate HTML pages and JavaScript, and loading the JavaScript only as and when you need it. I've heard people recommend a single-page architecture approach, although the difference there is that the HTML pages and JavaScript are injected in and loaded as and when they are needed.

See part 4 here in this [PhoneGap tutorial](http://coenraets.org/blog/phonegap-tutorial/) for more information on properly implementing a single-page architecture.

It's not a good idea to load everything into memory at the start... it's an inefficient use of resources - as you can see from the slow performance.

And having separate HTML and JavaScript files should also be a lot easier to manage and understand as well.

Comment: I have read that tutorial, and it is the best one I have seen by far in terms of architecture of a PG application. I was just asking really if loading all the JS at the start would make a difference to the app responsiveness throughout. Thanks for the answer

Comment: It's also important to understand how jQuery Mobile manages the DOM. The larger your DOM is the more memory you consume that can degrade performance. When a new page is injected, the former page (unless it was in the default source) is flagged for removal. This helps to keep the DOM as small as possible. Multi-page documents don't account for those issues. The one outstanding concern you might have is that specific JS isn't executed on page load, so you may need to bind into some page lifecycle events if you have custom JS to lazy load or need executed on new pages.

Answer (score 0):

After loading the too much data ~(250 records in listview) in jquery mobile page DOM. The navigation sytem transits very slow. I have tried verious tricks but unsuccessful. finally, I got the exceptable performance of navigation by applying below tricks.

1. Try to remove/hide the populated data from DOM when trying to change page.
2. when come back to page. repopulate it.

Comment: Also, Try to minimise the HTML structure. as some HTML tags are slow in rendering. if you need to manipulate the HTML using HTML tags then try to use the virtual DOm strategy.